# Simple non-homogeneous ode with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the below differential equation but i miss something :
$$y''+y'+y = 1$$
$$y(0)=0 , y'(0)=0$$
The homogeneous is y(t) = 0. But i cannot find the non-homogeneous

Comment: Big HINT: Set $y=Const$

Comment: What function $y$ will make the left side equal to the right side? It's simple, don't overthink it!

Comment: Sorry but i am confused a lot if i set y(t) = 1 then how y(0)=0 ?

Comment: I solve it with matlab but i cannot conclude to this solution .

Comment: you set y(t) = 1 + (the general solution of the homogeneous). And then you apply your boundary conditions to fix the arbitrary constants in the general solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend i was very very confused ...